# Cannot save an image in Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am making a console recorder in Python.
But, when it tries to save 60.png in the FRAMES directory, It fails with error.
Here's my code:

```py
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
c = 1
def save():
    global c
    m = Image.new("RGB",(400,200),"#004c66")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(m)
    draw.text((5,5),text=output,fill=(255,255,255))
    with open(f"FRAMES/{c}.png","a+b") as fp:
        m.save(fp,"PNG")
    c+=1
output = 'Welcome to movieconsole!\nVersion: 0.1\n'
save()
with open('commands.txt') as fp:
  for i in fp.read().splitlines():
    if len(os.getcwd()) < 30:
        output += os.getcwd() + '$ '
    else:
        output += os.getcwd()[0:30] + '...$ '
    save()
    for l in i:
        output += l
        save()
    output += '\n'
    a = os.popen(i)
    for p in a.read().splitlines():
        output+=p+"\n"
        save()
        if len(output.splitlines()) > 12:
            output = '\n'.join(output.splitlines()[1::])
    if i[0:2] == 'cd':
        os.chdir(' '.join(i.split()[1::]))
    if len(output.splitlines()) > 12:
        output = '\n'.join(output.splitlines()[1::])
print(output)
```

And the error is:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FRAMES/60.png'`

Comment: with open(f"FRAMES/{c}.png","a+b") as fp:
Actually, this line is not need.You can save it directly without file object.

Comment: It gives same error without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you change directories whilst your program is running (in response to `cd` as input). Then when you try to write in a subdirectory called `FRAMES` it is no longer there.

I would suggest you use `Pathlib` (which is part of the standard library and doesn't need installing) and create an **absolute** path to your output directory at program startup, then use that when constructing the output filename:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Near start of code... create output dir and save absolute path
out = Path('FRAMES').absolute()
out.mkdir(exist_ok = True)
```

Then, later on, when you want to write frame 60:

```
i = 60
filepath = out / f'{i}.png'
image.save(str(filepath))
```

---

Note that an *absolute* path is one that begins with a slash and isn't affected by your changing directory. In contrast, a *relative* path is expressed relative to the current working directory, so it depends where you currently are in the filesystem.